# Which applications should I add in "permissions to other application" section in azure,to registering application for One Drive Business

Tags: c#, azure, office365, onedrive, office365api

I want to integrate one drive for business into my winform application.I have registered my application in azure for that.I created a trial office 365 account to test my implementation.I am able to authenticate user and I accepted all the permissions it asks during log in.I am able to get the "https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0" url for the logged in user and also the access token for calling one drive api's. But when I call the API to get the default drive or the files present at root level in the one drive business account, I get an unauthorized access error.I think I might not have added proper permissions while registering my application.I tried adding all the applications to permission list, but that also doesn't work.I am using this [link](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question which steps you have followed to register your app, but here is a link to a demo project in GitHub that does what I think you are trying to do. They give guidance to the set up which has two parts... registering with Azure and adding the connected service for Read/Write permissions.

Comment: I have provided the link in question, which I followed to implement one drive for business.Also please let me know the github link you are referring to.